# How to reset the step count from android

Tags: java, android

```
public class speedDetection extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private TextView textView;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
    private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;
   // boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_detection);


        //pass in the level from time to time.
        //int level = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("Level",0);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), level, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);

    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        float[] values = event.values;
        int stepsInSensor = -1;

        /*if (!flag) {
            //Reset the count when reset the apps
            int initValue = (int) values[values.length - 1];
            stepsInSensor = stepsInSensor - initValue;
        }*/

        if (values.length > 0) {                //some values was inside
            stepsInSensor = (int) values[0];    //the latest value added will be at value[0]
        }

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
            textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + stepsInSensor);

        } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
            textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + stepsInSensor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);

    }
}
```

Anyone have idea how to reset the `stepInSensor` started with 0 everytime the apps started?
the `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` can only reset when the device reboot.

I found a post answering this question was like "store the first value returned as initial value, then subtract subsequent value by it."

but how exactly it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's just math, right?

Store the initial step count when the app starts. When you try to get the new step value, simply subtract the initial value from the current step sensor value. That tells you exactly how many steps have been taken since the app started.

Comment: should it be implement from the onSensorChanged?
or how it should be represented in coding?

Comment: Well, you can calculate the value whenever there's a step. You should request the initial sensor value in `onCreate`. I'm not familiar with how to use that Sensor

Comment: Welcome. In any case, there is no explicit "reset"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
private static final String Initial_Count_Key = "FootStepInitialCount";
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
// Initialize if it is the first time use
if(!prefs.contains(Initial_Count_Key)){
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(Initial_Count_Key, stepsInSensor);
    editor.commit();
}
```

How to get the step count

```
// return -1 if it is not initialize
int startingStepCount = prefs.getInt(Initial_Count_Key, -1); 
int stepCount = stepsInSensor - startingStepCount;
```

How to reset (Reset the starting value)

```
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt(Initial_Count_Key, stepsInSensor);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: may i know from the code i uploaded if(values.length >0){ stepsInSensor = (int) values[0]; } there, i should actually reset the values[0], make it back to empty instead of reset the stepInSensor?

Comment: I assume `stepsInSensor` is the value you get from sensor.  Because you get the step count by calculataion, you set the initial count to current count equals to resetting.

Comment: float[] values = event.values;
 int stepsInSensor = -1;
if (values.length > 0) {               
            stepsInSensor = (int) values[0] ;    
        }
The way i get the step was from the sensorEvent .values put it into float[], so when i check the length of the values variable is more than 0, it means something inside then it will gv me the latest result from time to time, the key was i need the result from time to time, like 123456...
not just once, the code you share may reset the code but is only once, can't just simple loop it then.

Comment: that's is why i asking whether should think of reset the values variable back to empty float[] then get the things from 0. so call reset the counter

Comment: @EmilyGermanotta No, every time you want to reset, you just call the third code.